# Display decimals two digits unless integer

Tags: javascript, jquery, decimal, digits

Multiplication of two numbers

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input1, #input2").change(function () {
        var num = parseFloat($("#input1").val()) * parseFloat($("#input2").val());

        if (num % 1 != 0) {
            num = Math.floor(num * 100) / 100;
        } else {
            num = parseInt(num);
        }

        $("#input3").val(num);
    });
});
```

- If the result is integer as 10, it is written as 10. It is ok for me.
- If the result is as 10.01, it is written as 10.01. It is ok for me.
- But if the result is as 10.10, it is written as 10.1 instead of
  10.10.

  How do display "always" two digits only if there is any decimals?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/qjmve/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#input1, #input2").change(function () {
        var num = parseFloat($("#input1").val()) * parseFloat($("#input2").val());

        if (num != parseInt(num))
            num = num.toFixed(2);

        $("#input3").val(num);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the toFixed() function on numbers with decimals.

```
if(num.toString().indexOf('.') != -1)
    num = num.toFixed(2);
```

Comment: toFixed(2) makes all te numbers with two decimals, even 10.00. I do not need .00

Comment: My bad i'll account for that.